# How can I add multiple result sets in go-sqlmock?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a db query that returns 2 result sets and I would like to unit test the go function that performs this query.
While I can add and test rows like this:

```
myMockRows:=sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"col1","col2"}).AddRow("col1val1", "col2val2")
mock.ExpectQuery("my_stored_procedure").WithArgs(arg1, arg2).WillReturnRows(myMockRows)
```

I am not sure how to proceed with creating multiple result sets in my `rows` object. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
myMockRows:=sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"col1","col2"}).AddRow("col1val1", "col2val2")
myMockRows2:=sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"col3","col4"}).AddRow("col3val1", "col4val2")
mock.ExpectQuery("my_stored_procedure").WithArgs(arg1, arg2).WillReturnRows(myMockRows, myMockRows2)
```

Since `WillReturnRows` accepts multiple row objects and forms a slice, use it to construct the next Result Set.

Answer (score 5):

I had tried out, @Nikhil Vandanapu's answer and I wasn't getting the desired output. For some reason it took only `myMockRows` and `myMockRows2` was ignored. I did some reading and we can do the following to get it to return multiple rows.

```
myMockRows:=sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"col1","col2"})
.AddRow("col1val1", "col2val2")
.AddRow("col1val1", "col2val2")

mock.ExpectQuery("my_stored_procedure").WillReturnRows(myMockRows)
```

According to [godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock#Rows.AddRow). Value slice return the same instance to perform **subsequent** actions.

Adding this [blog](https://dev.to/ale_ukr/how-to-test-database-interactions-in-golang-applications-3041) post if you want an easier read about the topic

Comment: @Nikhil Vandanapu's answer works and deserves upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the way @Nikhil Vandanapu answered works perfectly. You have stated in your question that you wanted to add "Multiple Result Sets".  That's implies the usage of multiple queries and "NextResultSet()" as well, like this:

```
// Execute a query that returns multiple result sets
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * FROM table2;")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error executing query:", err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    // Process the first result set
    fmt.Println("Result set 1:")
    for rows.Next() {
        var col1, col2 string
        if err := rows.Scan(&col1, &col2); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Error scanning row:", err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Column 1:", col1)
        fmt.Println("Column 2:", col2)
    }

    // Move to the next result set
    if rows.NextResultSet() {
        // Process the second result set
        fmt.Println("Result set 2:")
        for rows.Next() {
            var col1, col2 int
            if err := rows.Scan(&col1, &col2); err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error scanning row:", err)
            }
            fmt.Println("Column 1:", col1)
            fmt.Println("Column 2:", col2)
        }
    }
```

In this scenario, Nikhil Vandanapu's solution works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your test rows inside a `struct` and then execute `loop` over the `struct` like below code.

```
 type args struct {
        val string
 }

 tests := []struct {
            name    string
            s       *<YourDBstruct>
            args    args
            wantErr bool
        }{
            {
                name:    "Test with correct value1",
                s:       &YourDBstruct{db},
                args:    args{"Val1"}
                wantErr: true,
            },
            {
                name:    "Test with correct value2",
                s:       &YourDBstruct{db},
                args:    args{"Val2"}
                wantErr: true,
            },
            {
                name:    "Test with correct valueN",
                s:       &YourDBstruct{db},
                args:    args{"ValN"}
                wantErr: true,
            },
        }
        for _, tt := range tests {
            t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
                mock.ExpectExec("my_stored_procedure")
                if err := tt.s.YourStoreFuncName(); (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                    t.Errorf("YourStoreFuncName() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
                }
            })
```